# PostgreSql query to sum all values in json array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, null, coalesce

I am writing this query for an use case on this table

```
______________________________________________________
|companyId |    detailsJson                          |
|----------| ----------------------------------------|
|12        |{"dataKeyOne":1.10, "dataKeyTwo":1.20}   |
|123       |{"dataKeyFour":2.12, "dataKeySeven":1.18}|
|134       |    {}                                   |
|342       |    {}                                   |
______________________________________________________
```

My output coming is after writing this query is :

```
select companyId, sum(value::float) as sum
      from tableA, jsonb_each_text(detailsJson)
group by companyId;
```

```
|companyId |    sum|
|----------|-------|
|12        |  2.30 |
|123       |  3.30 |
```

But I want if detailsJson is empty then I want these companyId with 0 sum as shown in table below :

```
|companyId |    sum|
|----------|-------|
|12        |  2.30 |
|123       |  3.30 |
|134       |  0.0  |
|342       |  0.0  |
```

How can I achieve this using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `jsonb_each_text` to the FROM clause so that you can use it in an outer join:

```
select t.companyid, 
       sum(d.value::float) as sum
from the_table t
   left join jsonb_each_text(t.detailsjson) as d(key, value) on true
group by t.companyid
order by t.companyid
;
```

Comment: Thanks 
a_horse_with_no_name for answering , From this query I am getting Null values for 134 and 342 companyId , I want 0.0 values for 134 and 342 company id .

Comment: @AnkitKumar: then use `coalesce()`